# Enough to change @media for customize max width in bootstrap grid?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want my page to be max-width 960px.
Is it enough to change css to:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
     width: 960px;
  }
}
```

or do i miss something and must customize through http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ to cover all CSS and JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the media container.

Just use the max-width property:

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
}
```